# Erro 1452 mysql: Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, sql

Criei as seguintes tabelas e fiz populate em 2 (utilizador e tipo);

CREATE:

```
CREATE TABLE utilizador(utilizador_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, morada VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, numero_cc INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE produtos(id_produto INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, genero CHAR(1) NOT NULL, preco INT NOT NULL,id_tipo INT);
CREATE TABLE tipo(id_tipo INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,designacao VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE cart_produtos(id_produtos INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,quantidade INT,valor INT,id_cart INT);
CREATE TABLE cart_utilizador(id_cart INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,id_utilizador INT);
CREATE TABLE cart(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,datas DATE NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE cart_utilizador ADD CONSTRAINT id_utilizador_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (id_utilizador_fk) REFERENCES utilizador(utilizador_id);

ALTER TABLE cart_produtos ADD CONSTRAINT id_cart_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (id_cart) REFERENCES cart_utilizador(id_cart);

ALTER TABLE produtos ADD CONSTRAINT id_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (id_produto) REFERENCES cart_produtos(id_produtos);

ALTER TABLE cart_utilizador ADD CONSTRAINT id_cart_produtos_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (id_cart) REFERENCES cart_produtos(id_produtos);

ALTER TABLE produtos ADD CONSTRAINT id_tipo_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (id_tipo) REFERENCES tipo(id_tipo);

ALTER TABLE cart ADD CONSTRAINT id_cart_prime_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES cart_utilizador(id_cart);
```

POPULATE:

```
INSERT INTO utilizador(username,password,morada,email,numero_cc) VALUES("ricardinho","oscarpw","Rua dos Aliados","rida@gmail.com",123349574);
INSERT INTO utilizador(username,password,morada,email,numero_cc) VALUES("blitzo","maidpw","Rua das Carrinhas","blibli@gmail.com",139845923);
INSERT INTO utilizador(username,password,morada,email,numero_cc) VALUES("ricstu","glamorpw","Rua dos Aliados","ritold@gmail.com",188957923);
INSERT INTO utilizador(username,password,morada,email,numero_cc) VALUES("jacintosr","jckoneilpw","Avenida das Ameijoas","rida@gmail.com",123349574);
INSERT INTO tipo(designacao) VALUES("calca");

INSERT INTO tipo(designacao) VALUES("chapeu");

INSERT INTO tipo(designacao) VALUES("camisola");
```

Quando faço o populate da tabela produtos com este script:

```
INSERT INTO produtos(nome,genero,preco,id_tipo) VALUES("calca preta com riscas","M",18,1);
```

Acontece-me o erro (Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`loja`.`produtos`, CONSTRAINT `id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_produto`) REFERENCES `cart_produtos` (`id_produtos`))
)

Como resolvo isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```
ALTER TABLE produtos ADD CONSTRAINT id_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (id_produto) REFERENCES cart_produtos(id_produtos);
```

Com isso para criar um registro em produtos, precisa utilizar um id_produto existente em cart_produtos.

Comment: Então, para resolver isso tenho que eliminar a relação e fazer populate primeiro e depois fazer esse script? @karran

Comment: o que eu acredito que você quer é `ALTER TABLE cart_produtos ADD CONSTRAINT id_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (id_produtos) REFERENCES produtos(id_produto);`

Comment: nesse caso você teria que remover a relação antiga e adicionar essa nova, talvez haja mais problemas, @fabimetabi

Comment: tem razao faz mais sentido a relação dessa maneira, amanha irei testar obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado, se tudo der certo por favor depois marque a minha resposta como solução