# Comoresolver o erro ERROR 1452 (23000) no mysql

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando popular o seguinte banco de dados:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS library;

CREATE DATABASE library;

USE library;

CREATE TABLE AUTHOR (
  NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  COUNTRY VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  TITLE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (NAME,TITLE)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE BOOK (
  TITLE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  ISBN CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PUBLISHER VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  SUBJECT VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ISBN)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE WRITES (
  NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  TITLE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  ISBN CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (NAME,ISBN)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

ALTER TABLE WRITES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BOOK_WRITES
  FOREIGN KEY(ISBN) REFERENCES BOOK(ISBN)
  ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE WRITES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHOR_WRITES
  FOREIGN KEY(NAME) REFERENCES AUTHOR(NAME)
  ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

INSERT INTO AUTHOR (NAME,COUNTRY,TITLE) VALUES("Dorothy King","England","Springtime Gardening");
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (NAME,COUNTRY,TITLE) VALUES("Jon Nkoma","Kenya","Birds of Africa");
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (NAME,COUNTRY,TITLE) VALUES("Won Lau","China","Early Tangs Paintings");
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (NAME,COUNTRY,TITLE) VALUES("Bert Kovalsco","United States","Baskets for Today");
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (NAME,COUNTRY,TITLE) VALUES("Tom Quercos","Mexico","Mayan Art");
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (NAME,COUNTRY,TITLE) VALUES("Jimmy Chan","China","Early Tangs Paintings");
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (NAME,COUNTRY,TITLE) VALUES("Dorothy King","England","Autumn Annuals");
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (NAME,COUNTRY,TITLE) VALUES("Jane East","United States","Springtime Gardening");

INSERT INTO BOOK (TITLE,ISBN,PUBLISHER,SUBJECT) VALUES("Springtime Gardening","0816354219","Harding","Nature");
INSERT INTO BOOK (TITLE,ISBN,PUBLISHER,SUBJECT) VALUES("Early Tangs Paintings","036487547X","Ballman","Art");
INSERT INTO BOOK (TITLE,ISBN,PUBLISHER,SUBJECT) VALUES("Birds of Africa","0115012141","Loraine","Nature");
INSERT INTO BOOK (TITLE,ISBN,PUBLISHER,SUBJECT) VALUES("Springtime Gardening","0560001428","Swift-Key","Nature");
INSERT INTO BOOK (TITLE,ISBN,PUBLISHER,SUBJECT) VALUES("Baskets for Today","0816537054","Harding","Art");
INSERT INTO BOOK (TITLE,ISBN,PUBLISHER,SUBJECT) VALUES("Autumn Annuals","0816885060","Harding","Nature");

INSERT INTO WRITES (NAME,TITLE,ISBN) VALUES("Jimmy Chan","Early Tangs Paintings","036487547X");
INSERT INTO WRITES (NAME,TITLE,ISBN) VALUES("Dorothy King","Autumn Annuals","0816885060");
INSERT INTO WRITES (NAME,TITLE,ISBN) VALUES("Jane East","Springtime Gardening",0560001428);
INSERT INTO WRITES (NAME,TITLE,ISBN) VALUES("Bert Kovalsco","Baskets for Today","0816537054");
INSERT INTO WRITES (NAME,TITLE,ISBN) VALUES("Won Lau","Early Tangs Paintings","036487547X");
INSERT INTO WRITES (NAME,TITLE,ISBN) VALUES("Jon Nkoma","Birds of Africa","0115012141");
INSERT INTO WRITES (NAME,TITLE,ISBN) VALUES("Dorothy King","Springtime Gardening","0816354219");
```

Porém recebo seguinte erro:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`library`.`WRITES`, CONSTRAINT `FK_BOOK_WRITES` FOREIGN KEY (`ISBN`) REFERENCES `BOOK` (`ISBN`))
```

Já há uma [pergunta semelhante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220885/erro-1452-mysql-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row), mas não me ajudou muito.

Comment: Porque você não referencia a chave estrangeira pelo codigo primário da outra tabela?

Comment: Estou seguindo um exemplo pra treinar como exercício do livro "Fundamentos matemáticos para Ciência da Computação" e gostaria de mater as referencias como estão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na realidade existe uma "gambiarra" que você pode fazer, porém se há erro de `constraint` seus dados não ficarão íntegros em relação a chave estrangeira, mas para sanar seu problema e você pelo menos poder inserir seus dados, desabilite a verificação de chave estrangeira no inicio do seu `script` e habilite novamente no final, dessa maneira.

Desabilitar : `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`

Habilitar: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`

Não aconselho fazer isso, porém resolve seu problema por hora.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado! Quando descobrir uma maneira mais adequada de contornar o problema `constraint` postarei aqui.

Comment: Na realidade, não conferi, mas parece que os dados não estão conseguindo fazer referência entre si, tem que ver tipos de campos, se o dado que faz referência está correto mesmo.

Comment: Bom dia @RenanRosa analisei o script do seu post para resolver seu problema.
Então, seu problema é um erro de sintaxe simples, sua constraint é entre campos `CHAR(10)`.
Nessa linha você possui um erro: 
`INSERT INTO WRITES (NAME,TITLE,ISBN) VALUES("Jane East","Springtime Gardening",0560001428);` o campo que está sendo inserindo está sem aspas("), sendo assim o banco de dados interpetra como um `NUMBER`, onde dá erro de referência, basta colocar o campo entre aspas e tudo certo!

Comment: Realmente, está tudo completamente operacional agora! Grato!